# baklavajs event on node select in VueJs3

Tags: events, charts, vuejs3

how to track which nodes are selected with an event in a baklavajs-graph in vue3 and composition api.

```
import { BaklavaEditor, useBaklava } from "@baklavajs/renderer-vue";
const baklava = useBaklava();
const editor = baklava.editor;

//works
editor.graphEvents.beforeAddConnection.subscribe(token, (conn, prevent) => {
    // Prevent connections to the same node
    if (conn.to.connectionCount > 0) {
        prevent();
        return;
    }
});

//does not work
editor.nodeEvents.on("nodeSelected", (node) => {
    console.log("Selected node ID:", node.id);
});
```